# Export JSON from dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| A | B | tc-01 | tc-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bapc | act | 1 | 1 |
| bapc | bp | 2 | 2 |
| bapc | ly | 3 | 3 |
| bapc | vsLy | 4 | 4 |
| bapc | bsBp | 5 | 5 |
| nsr | act | 6 | 6 |
| nsr | bp | 7 | 7 |
| nsr | ly | 8 | 8 |
| nsr | vsLy | 9 | 9 |
| nsr | bsBp | 10 | 10 |

How can I export dataframe to the json file like this

```py
{               
    "expect": {         
        "tc-01": {      
            "bapc":{    
                "act":1,
                "bp":2,
                "ly":3,
                "vsLy":4,
                "bsBp":5
            },  
            "nsr":{ 
                "act":6,
                "bp":7,
                "ly":8,
                "vsLy":9,
                "bsBp":10
            }
        },
        "tc-02": {      
            "bapc":{    
                "act":1,
                "bp":2,
                "ly":3,
                "vsLy":4,
                "bsBp":5
            },  
            "nsr":{ 
                "act":6,
                "bp":7,
                "ly":8,
                "vsLy":9,
                "bsBp":10
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: It seems that pandas doesn't support this format out of the box so you have to write your own converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df.melt(['A', 'B']).set_index(['variable', 'A', 'B'])\
  .unstack('B')['value'].groupby('variable')\
  .apply(lambda x: x.droplevel(0).to_dict('index')).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'tc-01': {'bapc': {'act': 1, 'bp': 2, 'bsBp': 5, 'ly': 3, 'vsLy': 4},
  'nsr': {'act': 6, 'bp': 7, 'bsBp': 10, 'ly': 8, 'vsLy': 9}},
 'tc-02': {'bapc': {'act': 1, 'bp': 2, 'bsBp': 5, 'ly': 3, 'vsLy': 4},
  'nsr': {'act': 6, 'bp': 7, 'bsBp': 10, 'ly': 8, 'vsLy': 9}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertuples()` to loop over the dataframe and build a dictionary iteratively. Iterating with `itertuples()` is probably the most efficient method for the operation required in the OP as well.

```py
import json
res = {'expect': {}}
for a, b, tc01, tc02 in df.itertuples(index=False):
    # insert the key if it doesn't exist for the inner dicts
    # by using `setdefault()`
    res['expect'].setdefault('tc-01', {}).setdefault(a, {})[b] = tc01
    res['expect'].setdefault('tc-02', {}).setdefault(a, {})[b] = tc02
j_var = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
print(j_var)
```

```
{
    "expect": {
        "tc-01": {
            "bapc": {
                "act": 1,
                "bp": 2,
                "ly": 3,
                "vsLy": 4,
                "bsBp": 5
            },
            "nsr": {
                "act": 6,
                "bp": 7,
                "ly": 8,
                "vsLy": 9,
                "bsBp": 10
            }
        },
        "tc-02": {
            "bapc": {
                "act": 1,
                "bp": 2,
                "ly": 3,
                "vsLy": 4,
                "bsBp": 5
            },
            "nsr": {
                "act": 6,
                "bp": 7,
                "ly": 8,
                "vsLy": 9,
                "bsBp": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some reshaping with `stack`, `unstack` and `pivot`

```
s = df.pivot('A', 'B').stack(0)
s.assign(r=s.to_dict('records'))['r'].unstack().to_dict()
```

---

```
{'tc-01': {'bapc': {'act': 1, 'bp': 2, 'bsBp': 5, 'ly': 3, 'vsLy': 4},
           'nsr': {'act': 6, 'bp': 7, 'bsBp': 10, 'ly': 8, 'vsLy': 9}},
 'tc-02': {'bapc': {'act': 1, 'bp': 2, 'bsBp': 5, 'ly': 3, 'vsLy': 4},
           'nsr': {'act': 6, 'bp': 7, 'bsBp': 10, 'ly': 8, 'vsLy': 9}}}
```